# HERE API Pass Thru Waypoints

Tags: here-api

Using the Routing REST API I need to be able to modify the default route.  To do that, I can add pass thru waypoints when calling calculateroute.  For example, if I am traveling from *Edmonton, AB* to *Calgary, AB* but I want to go via a different highway, I can geocode *Stettler, AB* and use the three waypoints in the call to the API.  However, I’m finding that the turn by turn instructions are going at the street level to the center of Stettler, AB, but I just want to stay on the highway and pass through Stettler.  How can I specify pass thru waypoints (through/near a town) that are not routing specifically to the exact coordinate?

Answer (score 0):

The Routing API uses the specified waypoints and your travel mode (car, truck, fastest, shortest, traffic, etc) to find the best routes. To go through locations that you desire, your waypoints should be at/close to those locations. Also, you can specify if you want alternate routes to be calculated, then you can choose the route that you desire. You can also use the avoidAreas parameter to avoid certain areas you do not want the route to pass through.

Comment: I can't use "alternate route" per se because we are trying to route around a bad weather area. Our bad weather area is a polygon and may not be close to a rectangle, which is what avoidAreas requires.  Typically, the user is specifying a town to pass through that avoids the bad weather area.  Sadly, when close to the town, the route directions go street by street, turn by turn, to the center of the town.

Comment: Any more thoughts from the HERE team?